# How to detect if an in memory DOM element is a block element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have some HTML as a string and i need to wrap all inline elements inside a `p` tag, without actually rendering them.

**Example:**

```
<h2>Some heading</h2>
<p>Some content</p>
<strong>Some inline content</strong>
```

should be converted to

```
<h2>Some heading</h2>
<p>Some content</p>
<p><strong>Some inline content</strong></p>
```

I am processing the html by creating an in memory DOM.

```
function ensureRootLevelBlockTags(html) {
    const psuedoDom = document.createElement('div');
    psuedoDom.innerHTML = html;

    const childNodes = psuedoDom.childNodes;
    for (let i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
        const currentNode = childNodes[i];
        if (/* is currentNode is not a block element */) {
            const newNode = document.createElement('p');
            newNode.append(currentNode);
            psuedoDom.insertBefore(newNode, childNodes[i]);
        }
    }

    return psuedoDom.innerHTML;
}

ensureRootLevelBlockTags('<h2>Some heading</h2><p>Some content</p><strong>Some inline content</strong>');
```

I need the condition I can use to check if the element is a block element.

## Edit:

We were already using tinymce in the project, and found that `tinymce.html.Schema` object contains a list of valid tags and their valid children. I ended up using that as reference to check if i can wrap the element inside `p`.

Comment: check if the tagName of the node is one of `div`, `h1` or whatnot (https://www.google.com/search?q=html+block+elements&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b)

Comment: Why do you want to wrap them?

Comment: The requirement is I want only block elements as the direct children

Comment: @AvcS - There are no "block elements." There are elements with default styling as blocks, but that's not the same thing. I've posted an answer addressing what I think you mean by that (wrapping phrasing-only content). As far as I know, you can't query that dynamically, you're stuck with a list.

Comment: could you just set the display property to to block on all child items rather than wrapping them?  it should have a similar effect. 

Also, it's not valid css to have block level elements inside <p> elements (the <p> will self-close), so wrapping with <p> elements means you may get unexpected results.

Comment: @allan sorry for the misunderstanding, i wanted to wrap all elements that have display: inline or inline-block, I want the check for display: block so that i can skip them. I have updated the code

Comment: Also the actual requirement is i need to accumulate all consecutive inline elements into a single block,so I cant use dispay: block on all child elements :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're really looking for "block" elements (this is based in part on your comment on my incorrect — now deleted — answer). As far as I can tell, you're looking for top-level elements that can appear only in [*phrasing content*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#phrasing-content-2) and you want to wrap them in something that can appear in [*flow* content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#flow-content-2).

But the thing about the content categories is that most phrasing content is also perfectly valid flow content; from [Kinds of Content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#kinds-of-content) in the spec:

[image]

The only way I see to do what you're describing is to hardcode the list of phrasing-only element types and check the tag names against that list in the loop.

That list is currently:

- `a`
- `abbr`
- `area` (if it is a descendant of a map element)
- `audio`
- `b`
- `bdi`
- `bdo`
- `br`
- `button`
- `canvas`
- `cite`
- `code`
- `data`
- `datalist`
- `del`
- `dfn`
- `em`
- `embed`
- `i`
- `iframe`
- `img`
- `input`
- `ins`
- `kbd`
- `label`
- `link` (if it is allowed in the body)
- `map`
- `mark`
- `math` (MathML)
- `meta` (if the itemprop attribute is present)
- `meter`
- `noscript`
- `object`
- `output`
- `picture`
- `progress`
- `q`
- `ruby`
- `s`
- `samp`
- `script`
- `select`
- `slot`
- `small`
- `span`
- `strong`
- `sub`
- `sup`
- `svg` (SVG)
- `template`
- `textarea`
- `time`
- `u`
- `var`
- `video`
- `wbr`

You can probably omit some of those (such as `link`).

But again, they're valid flow content, so it's not necessary to wrap them.

Comment: @t-j-crowder thank you for the explanation and pointing in the right direction about "block elements" :D,  hard coding the list of tags seems to be the only way for now

Answer (score 0):

Use the [element `tagName` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) to check if the node/element is one of block-level elements (eg https://www.google.com/search?q=html+block+elements&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b gives the following elements as block-level)

- p.
- h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6.
- ol, ul.
- pre.
- address.
- blockquote.
- dl.
- div.

So something like the following should do:

```
const BLOCK_LEVEL = {'DIV':1, 'DL':1, 'BLOCKQUOTE':1 /*, ..*/};
// rest code here
const currentNode = childNodes[i];
   if (currentNode.tagName && BLOCK_LEVEL[currentNode.tagName]) {
       // is block-level element, handle accordingly
   }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using the `node.style.display` element. the results will either be `block`, `inline`, `none`, or `inline-block`.

Comment: The value of `style.display` can be ""